# How Does Data Transfer Between Azure Regions Work?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

for example if I need to collect data from Europe and Asia to  US, how would it work and what speed should I expect and what price do I need ?

Answer (score 3):

The data transfer within the region is free but the data egress across regions is charged. You should consider enabling [Read-Access Geographically Redundant Storage (RA-GRS)](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/12/12/announcing-public-preview-of-read-access-geo-redundant-storage/), at the storage account level which allows you read an eventually-consistent copy of your data saved in a different region. If you are looking at moving existing data, check costs and other details on [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2014/08/12/azure-storage-essential-facts-august-2014-definitely-subject-to-change.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Copying from one storage to another storage is very fast and you don't need great internet speed for that. For pricing on bandwidth you need to check the azure pricing calculator

Answer (score 0):

One way to transfer data is by using the AZCopy utility http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-azcopy/

Storage limits can be found on this link http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/

Data transfer pricing can be found here http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/